# counting instances in previous year

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large data set of hospital admissions. For each admission I would like to know the number of admissions that took place within the previous year.
My dataset is in a form of a dataframe including patient ID and hospitalization date.
I would like to have an additional column stating the counts of admissions in the previous year - for example, column "hosp_past_year" in the table below.

| patient_id | hospitalization_date | hosp_past_year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nov 2 2020 | 2 |
| 1 | Dec 20 2019 | 1 |
| 1 | Nov 30 2019 | 1 |
| 1 | Jan 1 2015 | 0 |
| 2 | April 17 2019 | 1 |
| 2 | Nov 5 2018 | 0 |

I had written the code below (which works), but would love to hear suggestions for making it more simple and less time-consuming to run.

```
pat_l=list(df.patient_id.unique())
df["hospitalization_date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["hospitalization_date"])
df_fin=pd.DataFrame()
for pat in pat_l:
    df_pat=df[df.patient_id==pat]
    df_pat=df_pat.reset_index()
    temp_df=pd.DataFrame()

    for i in range(len(df_pat)):
        temp_df[i]=(df_pat["hospitalization_date"]-df_pat["hospitalization_date"][i]).dt.days

    temp_df=np.where(temp_df>=0,0,np.where(temp_df>-366,1,0))
    df_pat["hosp_past_year"]=temp_df.sum(axis=0)
    df_fin=df_fin.append(df_pat)
```

any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Following would produce your desired result,

```
res = df.groupby(['patient_id',df['hospitalization_date'].dt.year]).sum().reset_index()
pd.merge(df,res,how='left', left_on= ['patient_id',df['hospitalization_date'].dt.year], right_on = ['patient_id','hospitalization_date'],suffixes=['_x','_sum'])[['patient_id','hospitalization_date_x','previous_year_x','previous_year_sum']]
```

Output:

```
patient_id  hospitalization_date_x  previous_year_x previous_year_sum
0   1   2020-11-02  2   2
1   1   2019-12-20  1   1
2   1   2019-11-30  0   1
3   1   2015-01-01  0   0
4   2   2019-04-17  1   1
5   2   2018-11-05  0   0
```

Comment: thanks @k33da_the_bug. But the hospitalizations in the previous year (now the "hosp_past_year") is the result column Im looking for.. not to be used in the code. I now edited it to make it more clear